# how to load a web page awesomium web control by clicking on a target link one of a search loaded web sites inside the web control

Tags: url, hyperlink, load, target, awesomium

Good day ! Could you give me a hand guys? I created windows forms search app with awesomium ,after search gets done and webcontrol1 loads the search results how user can load url by clicking on a target link of one of the search results? How to load the page by clicking on a target link in same webcontrol1?

[State of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaWdS.png)

when you click on a target link search page disappear and you wait forever and it never loads,
how to load it to the web control ,how to do it?

tried to find information on a event of a web control that does it ,but no luck

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Good day ! The problem resolved by rebuilding the project in another environment ,switched from windows server 2012 r2 to windows 10 ,heating target links work automat without doing anything and load correctly to webControl1. You can mark it as solved